# How do I trigger a cron job with codeception?

Tags: php, cron, codeception

let me start by saying I am new to codeception, and I tried searching for a solution online, but I didn't get anywhere.

Is there a way to trigger a cron job either through codeception or php?

Comment: OT: Why would you want to do that?

Comment: Say you have a php program that runs from cron and under certain circumstances needs to schedule another cron job or jobs based on some result in the first job.

Comment: Cronjobs are launched by crond based on time, if you want to run a particular command from php, execute it with system() or exec()

Comment: It works like this: The product manager creates a promotion, the cron runs at night, checks all prices, competition prices, margins, availability etc and generates a request that is reviewed by the product manager and accepted. During my tests I run the cron manually with Putty, and I need a way to automate this process.

Answer (score 0):

**First** install a new crontab

See: [How To Use Cron To Automate Tasks On a VPS](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-cron-to-automate-tasks-on-a-vps)

**Second** execute this command in crontab:

cd /YOUR_CODECEPTION_PROJECT_PATH && php vendor/bin/codecept run

For example:

$ crontab -e

```
SHELL=/bin/bash
HOME=/home/ubuntu

*/2 * * * * cd /var/www/html/test_prices && php vendor/bin/codecept run
```

It works in ubuntu 16.04 with codeception 2.5.